# How to schedule job in node js?

Tags: node.js

How can we schedule our job in `node.js`? Is there any way to achieve this? Is there any way except `cron` job?

We have a tender model and want to change status after closing date has passed.

Which way would be best?

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
var SpreeOpenTenders = sequelize.define(
  "SpreeOpenTenders",
  {
    tender_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    created_by: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    tender_closing_date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    announcement_date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    expected_delivery_date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE
    },
    state: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: "Open",
      comment: "Open, On going, Bid selection, Completed"
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Schedule Node.js job every five minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011962/schedule-node-js-job-every-five-minutes)

Comment: No @MaximSagaydachny, in that function will call every time but we want to run it once when the time has been out.

Comment: And how will you know that time run out unless you check it?

Comment: You can use schedule function in agenda.js .  https://github.com/agenda/agenda

Comment: Do not schedule cron through node.js code. I suggest not to accept any tender after the date has been passed. Customize your code on Dates and time bases.

Comment: Hi @mehta-rohan
Can you please give an example how we can achieve this and How status will be updated in database?

Answer (score 0):

You can use node-scheduler, check the link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Answer (score 0):

There are some techniques through which we can derive a value depending on another value in a `Schema`. But that case is only triggered on data update or creation. So, this method will not be useful in your scenario.

So, according to my knowledge, you cannot avoid `cron` job. The thing you can do is look for a `Node.js` `cron` job scheduler that requires minimal resources to execute. One of the scheduler that i personally use is [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron).

Hope this will help you.